# The draw_image() function from cowplot results in blurred pdfs

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

Reading a vectorized pdf sometimes result in a badly blurred image with the `draw_image()` function from cowplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(magick)

# make pdf input as example
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, shape = Species)) + 
  geom_point() + scale_shape_manual(values = 21:23) + theme_classic()
ggsave("input.pdf", p, width = 6, height = 4.2)

# now draw with draw_image() and then write as png
fig <- ggdraw() + draw_image("input.pdf")
ggsave("output.png", fig, width = 1, height = .7, dpi = 1200) # blurred image
```

[image]

However, reading SVGs works fine:

```
fig <- ggdraw() +
  draw_image("http://jeroen.github.io/images/tiger.svg")
ggsave("output.png", fig, width = 1, height = .7, dpi = 1200)
```

[image]

Also, using:

```
magick::image_read_pdf("input.pdf")
```

results in a non-blurry output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why SVGs and pdfs are handled differently, or what exactly happens when you read pdfs with `magick::image_read()` (which is what `draw_image()` uses internally), but one solution is to use `magick::image_read_pdf()` inside of `draw_image()`. The function `magick::image_read_pdf()` converts the pdf into a raster image, and we can specify the resolution we want with the `density` argument:

```
fig <- ggdraw() + draw_image(magick::image_read_pdf("input.pdf", density = 600))
ggsave("output.png", fig, width = 1, height = .7, dpi = 1200)
```

[image]